# Laravel How To use another server as file storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem, thephpleague

I am using Laravel 7.6:

I have two Laravel projects in each server (server is normal server. Neither AWS nor Digital Ocean, Just dedicated server).

Project1 is in server1.

Project2 is in server2.

My question is:

How can I do CRUD from Project1 To server2?

So in Project1 I would like to read, upload, delete, edit files which are in server2.
This is my current filesystem configuration.

```
  'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],
```

**Can I make and use something like this?**

```
           'public' => [
                'driver' => 'custom',
                'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
                'url' => 'my-another-server-url',
                'visibility' => 'public',
            ],
```

I think this is quite possible if two projects are in same server (using local driver).

Both server can be provided by the same hosting provider but I will put them in each server.

I think this [package (https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem)](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) gives me some solution.

Should I make API in project 2?

Can anyone help me with some instruction and recommending packages?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use ftp or sftp to access the another server: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#driver-prerequisites

Comment: You may consider AWS S3 for this - N applications may share the same data storage.

Comment: Thanks, ftp configuration seems good.